# Update all fields except one field

Tags: laravel

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $house = House::find($id);
        $house->name = $request->name;
        $house->code = $request->code;
        $house->description = $request->description;
        $house->address = $request->address;
        $house->owner_name = $request->owner_name;
        $house->manager_name = $request->manager_name;
        if($house->update()){
            return redirect()->route('houses')
            ->with('alert.status', 'success')
            ->with('alert.message', 'Successfully Updated.');
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->route('houses')
            ->with('alert.status', 'danger')
            ->with('alert.message', 'Try Again.');
        } 
    }
```

Here i want to update all my fields except code when the code already exists in the database.How can i do that please give some solution.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **null coalescing operator**, available in php version 7.

In short, you can do this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $house = House::find($id);

    $house->code = $house->code ?? $request->code;
    $house->save();

}
```

If **$house->code** is different from null, this will be used if it will not use **$request->code**.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use a `if` :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $house = House::find($id);
        $house->name = $request->name;
        if($house->code == NULL)
        $house->code = $request->code;
        $house->description = $request->description;
        $house->address = $request->address;
        $house->owner_name = $request->owner_name;
        $house->manager_name = $request->manager_name;
        $house->save();
        if($house->update()){
            return redirect()->route('houses')
            ->with('alert.status', 'success')
            ->with('alert.message', 'Successfully Updated.');
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->route('houses')
            ->with('alert.status', 'danger')
            ->with('alert.message', 'Try Again.');
        } 
    }
```

You should use the `save()` method after you made all this changes.

Answer (score 0):

do this way with ternary condition :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $house = House::find($id);

         $house->code = !empty($house->code) && $house->code!= NULL ? $house->code : $request->code;

   }
```

Comment: I have already written some code which works perfectly.But problem is when i change code it works but if i don't change code it creates problem.Because if i don't change the code it gets its value as exists in database and makes problem.i give my code below.please check
if (House::where('code', '=', Input::get('code'))->exists()) {
            return redirect('/houses/edit/'.$house->id)
            ->with('alert.status', 'danger')
            ->with('alert.message', 'House code already exist.');
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can check for code existence on database by `Eloquent: Mutators` like below on your `House` Model

```
class House extends Model
{
    //your codes
    public function setCodeAtrribute($value)
    {
        if ($this->attributes["code"] != null) $this->attributes["code"] = $value
    }
}
```

You can also check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators) for more information